# Python problem with opening files from other folder

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

```
+-- Project
+-- Database
|   +-- Mybase.txt  
+-- test
|   +-- testfile.py
+--somefile.py
```

my function:

```
def easy_check_ang_word(random_number): 
    with open("Database/Mybase.txt", "r") as ang_base_file:
        ang_base = ang_base_file.readlines()

    ang_base_file.close()
    return ang_base[random_number]
```

My project folder is mark as Sources
In somefile.py i have a function that returns me a string from Mybase.txt, it works well, but when i try to test it in testfile.py i have an Error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Database/Mybase.txt'
what its wrong?
moreover i tried to change Database/Mybase.txt to ../Database/Mybase.txt and it works well i test but in main no.

Comment: You’re better off using the full path, your debugging has shown you the relative path will fix it in one place but unless you have a way of injecting that i via environment variables etc you need a full path

Comment: so what i should change? On this project we are working on it several so i think i cant put full path if it should works for all of us.

Comment: You need something common, whether thats built up via the working directory is up to you - `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "database", "mybase.txt")`

Comment: what this comand do?

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative paths. For `testfile.py` to find that file, as opposed to `somefile.py`, in your current directory structure, you would access it like `../Database/Mybase.txt`. If you want to always find a specific file from anywhere on your system, you would need to use an an absolute path, such as `/home/me/a_file` on Unix-likes or `C:\Users\me\a_file` on Windows.

Comment: what I should write that worked in both situations?

Comment: @HGH For it to work for both scripts, use the latter option of absolute paths. The full path will depend where the top-directory you've provided is stored on your system.

Comment: okay if i put full path it works, but this is a project that works on 5 people. So what i should put into this path  to make it work everyone? When it was only main.py the short path: Database/Mybase.txt was fine for all. But how to connect this with whole team and tests?